# Are all esterification reactions reversible? What is their general mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, esters

For example the reaction of ethanoic acid with ethanol is reversible, however is this true for **all** esters? I'm not quite whether it is as easy for a reversible reaction to occur both ways. Is there a limit to the complexity an ester can be? What would be the general mechanism for these reactions? I assume there is no limit on the complexity (carbon chain length) of esters, other than the frequency of longer-chain carboxylic acids and alcohols needed to form them. Is this true?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question referring to complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start this answer off with saying that both of these answers were the first result when searching for Google.

Yes, [The esterification reaction is both slow and reversible](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/alcohols/esterification.html)

and here is the mechanism from an image search

[image]

Comment: Do you also know whether esterification takes longer/ is more difficult with longer-chain carboxylic acids and alcohols?

Comment: Yes the rate of the mechanism slows with the size of the reactants.